# Объединить 2 двухмерных массива PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Есть 2 массива:

```
    $address_1 = array(
    'address' => array('address1' => "some")
);
$address_2 = array(
    'address' => array('address2' => "some_1")
);
```

Нужно их объединить, что бы на выходе было

```
$addresses = array(
        'address' => array(
            'address1' => "some",
            'address2' => "some_1"
        )
    );
```

Помогите, плиз, а то уже час сижу - не могу придумать, как это сделать.

Comment: `$addresses = array_merge_recursive($address_1, $address_2)`

Comment: $addresses = array_merge_recursive($address_1, $address_2)
Спасибо. То, что нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$addresses = array_merge_recursive($address_1, $address_2)